# Sorry,This video cannot be played! Error/PlayerDriver

Tags: android, url, video, video-streaming

I'm having problems playing my video on my Samsung Galaxy S ..it play fine if its from the sdcard but when I upload to a server and then send the url it gives me "Sorry, This video cannot be played". It's a .mp4 video and I converted it to android format using Sothink video converter.

This is my VideoView code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
       R.array.lecturehalls,R.layout.list_item));


final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.vid_links);

getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        String content = links[position];
        Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
               VideoOutput.class);
        showContent.setData(Uri.parse(content));
        startActivity(showContent);

          }




  });
}
```

Note: URL paths are stored in an array in strings.xml
It works fine when I use this link : http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp
my link works fine as well I tested it on my computer but when on the phone it doesn't work!

This is what I get :

```
12-14 02:11:01.621: ERROR/PlayerDriver(1287): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
```

EDIT:
VideoOutput class

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview);   


        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);


        Intent launchingIntent = getIntent();
        String content = launchingIntent.getData().toString();

    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

    videoView.setVideoPath(content);

    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.start();

    mediaController.show();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the streaming media playback is very finicky about the video files it likes to play.

If you can point your code to a different movie file and it works, then I would suggest either finding a different converter, or tweaking the settings related to the codec in yours and trying again. Or you could set it up to download the video the the SD and then play it from there.

EDIT:

I've had pretty good luck with Wondershare Video Converter Platinum. There is a free version I think, but I've ponied up the money for it once I tested it and found it to work for my needs.

Post the code that is inside your VideoOutput class also. That might help to shed some light on what is going on.

Also you should replace both instances of `getApplicationContext()` with `YourActivityName.this`. Using getApplicationContext() in this manner is prone to keeping copies of your context around in memory longer than they need to be. Plus your Activity already *is* a Context, so you don't need to get a new reference to a context with a larger scope.

Comment: I tried many different converters but still the same I tried changing the settings of the codec using HandBrake and now I get this error : "Sorry, this video is not valid for streaming to this device" .. I have more than one video and I need to play them from a server not SD

Comment: Thanks..I'll try the Wondershare Video Converter..see my edit for the VideoOutput class